# Reading Hive Tables in Spark Dataframe without header

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I have the following Hive table:

```
select* from employee;
OK
abc     19      da
xyz     25      sa
pqr     30      er
suv     45      dr
```

when I read this in spark(pyspark):

```
df = hiveCtx.sql('select* from spark_hive.employee')
df.show()
+----+----+-----+
|name| age| role|
+----+----+-----+
|name|null| role|
| abc|  19|   da|
| xyz|  25|   sa|
| pqr|  30|   er|
| suv|  45|   dr|
+----+----+-----+
```

I end up getting the headers in my spark DataFrame. Is there a simple way to remove it ?

Also, am I missing something while reading the table into the DataFrame (Ideally I shouldn't be getting the header right ?) ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Not the Most elegant way, but this worked with pyspark:

```
rddWithoutHeader = dfemp.rdd.filter(lambda line: line!=header) 
dfnew = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddWithoutHeader)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove header from the result. You can do like this:

```
scala> val df = sql("select * from employee")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show
+----+----+----+
|  id|name| age|
+----+----+----+
|null|name|null|
|   1| abc|  19|
|   2| xyz|  25|
|   3| pqr|  30|
|   4| suv|  45|
+----+----+----+

scala> val header = df.first()
header: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [null,name,null]

scala> val data = df.filter(row => row != header) 
data: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [id: int, name: string ... 1 more field]

scala> data.show
+---+----+---+
| id|name|age|
+---+----+---+
|  1| abc| 19|
|  2| xyz| 25|
|  3| pqr| 30|
|  4| suv| 45|
+---+----+---+
```

Thanks.

Comment: that's not what he asked for, when he fires query in hive he is getting the correct results but when firing the same query in spark using hive context getting the wrong results

Comment: I think hive remove header by default and in spark we have to remove header.

Comment: no that's not the case something else is going on using spark and hive for almost one year \

Comment: I had tried this in pyspark.
dfemp = df.filter(lambda line: line!=header)
Which gives me the error: condition should be string or Column

Comment: Not the Most elegant way, but this worked with pyspark:
rddWithoutHeader = dfemp.rdd.filter(lambda line: line!=header)
dfnew = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddWithoutHeader)

Comment: @Yash I don't know about the pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `skip.header.line.count` for skip this header. You could also specify the same while creating the table. For example:

```
create external table testtable ( id int,name string, age int)
row format delimited .............
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

after that load the data and then check your query I hope you will get expected output.

Comment: i did that when I created the tables with hive and I still get the headers with spark